# A Dictionary to replace occurrences of a string

Tags: c#, regex, dictionary

I am trying to replace occurrences of a property name with a value in a Dictionary<string, string> in C#.

I have the following Dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, string> properties = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { "property1", @"E:\" },
    { "property2", @"$(property1)\Temp"},
    { "property3", @"$(property2)\AnotherSubFolder"}
};
```

Where the key is the property name, and the value is just a string value.  I basically want to iterate over the values until all set properties have been replaced.  The syntax is similar to MSBuild property names.

This should eventually evaluate property 3 to `E:\Temp\AnotherSubFolder`.

It would help if the RegEx part of the functionality would work, which is where I am stuck on.

The following regex pattern works here:

```
/\$\(([^)]+)\)/g
```

Given the text:

```
$(property2)\AnotherSubFolder
```

It highlights the `$(property2)`.

However, putting this together in .NET fiddle, I don't get any matches with the following code:

```
var pattern = @"\$\(([^)]+)\)/g";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Matches(@"$(property2)AnotherSubFolder", pattern).Count);
```

Which outputs 0.

I am not too sure why here. Why is my match returning zero results?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to remove the "/g" as .Net does not see that as a switch, but as part of the pattern.

Comment: Additionally if you are going to test regular expressions that you want to use in .Net you should make sure to use a tool that actually uses .Net like http://regexhero.net/.

Comment: Yep good man.  The "/g" and the first "/" look like the offending pattern characters.  If I take them out I now get the match.  Put this on as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: RegEx hero.  New one to me - but unfortunately you have to pay by the looks of it.

Comment: I've never had to pay, just hit the try it now button.  Or just google for ".Net regular expression tester" there's more than one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. .NET should match globally by default.
2. I'm not aware of support for `/g` as that is a Perl-ism, so remove it, and the leading `/`, .NET is trying to match them literally.

Comment: Actually, its not specific to Perl, but Perl made it famous.

Answer (score 1):

Regular Expressions may be overkill here, and may even introduce issues if your properties or values contain special characters, or characters that will be evaluated as regular expressions themselves.

A simple replacement should work:

```
Dictionary<string, string> properties = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { "property1", @"E:\" },
    { "property2", @"$(property1)\Temp"},
    { "property3", @"$(property2)\AnotherSubFolder"}
};

Dictionary<string, string> newproperties = new Dictionary<string, string>();

// Iterate key value pairs in properties dictionary, evaluate values
foreach ( KeyValuePair<string,string> kvp in properties ) {
  string value = kvp.Value;
  // Execute replacements on value until no replacements are found
  // (Replacement of $(property2) will result in value containing $(property1), must be evaluated again)
  bool complete = false;
  while (!complete) {
    complete = true;
    // Look for each replacement token in dictionary value, execute replacement if found
    foreach ( string key in properties.Keys ) {
      string token = "$(" + key + ")";
      if ( value.Contains( token ) ) {
        value = value.Replace( "$(" + key + ")", properties[key] );
        complete = false;
      }
    }
  }
  newproperties[kvp.Key] = value;
}

properties = newproperties;
```

Comment: Thanks for that Brandon.  It might be overkill but it is done for now.  Lets see how it goes.